# Combine all the content from the multiple <p> tag inside a div, into a single string

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the html content as:

```
<div class="editor-box">
   <div class="insert-ad">
     Some ad content
   </div>
   <p>paragraph 1</p>
   <p>paragraph2</p>
   <p>paragraph3</p>
   <div class="media ad-item">
        Another Ad Content
    </div>
   <p>Paragraph4</p>
   <p>Paragraph5/p>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

I wanted to `merge` all the text inside the `<p>` element into a single string at once.

My final *OutputString* as:

```
string Output = "paragraph 1 paragraph2 paragraph3 Paragraph4 Paragraph5"
```

I have tried:

```
var doc = await GetAsync(href);
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='editor-box']/p"))
{
    string text = node.InnerText;
}
```

I have got the text from the  individual `<p>` element, But Is there any way to select all the content from `<p>` with a single query so that the i do not need to loop all the node and merge into a another string object.

Comment: simple google [search result](https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/14614318/xpath---select-text-of-selected-child-nodes) (it cost me 0.36 seconds)

Comment: @vasily.sib i have implemented with `stringbuilder`, but is there any option `so that the i do not need to loop to the node, while appending into a object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any reason if you don't want to manually loop over all the paragraph contents, you can always use LINQ and `string.Join` to achieve the same results.:

```
//1. Get the document
var doc = await GetAsync(href);

//2. Select all the paragraphs:
var paragraphNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='editor-box']/p");

//3. Select the content inside them:
var paragraphContentList = paragraphNodes.Select(node => node.InnerText);

//4. Join all the contents in a single string
var finalString = string.Join(" ", paragraphContentList);

//5. Done!
Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

Remember to use the LINQ namespace `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, i hope there isn't any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...
If you assign some id to your div element and also add `runat=server`.

```
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
       System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmltext = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                DivId.RenderControl(htmltext);
                string str = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

Here `DivId` is the `id` assigned to the `div`.

Comment: why `runat=server`? OP is trying to **parse** already existing HTML